# Problems while importing foundation js source files in webpack

Tags: zurb-foundation, webpack, amd, js-amd

I would like to import some foundation js files in a webpack app (jQuery is correctly defined).

In my entry js file I do the following:

```
import 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.core.js'; // this works
import 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.tabs.js'; // this works
import 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.reveal.js'; // this fails
```

The last one fails with the following error:

```
ERROR in ./~/foundation-sites/js/foundation.reveal.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'foundation' in /home/kai/Projects/myapp/node_modules/foundation-sites/js
 @ ./~/foundation-sites/js/foundation.reveal.js 474:4-476:6
```

So it seems there is a problem with all files that contain the code `define(['foundation'] ...` as `foundation` is not defined anywhere.

I installed `foundation-sites` (v6.0.5) using NPM.

How do I import those files that have the `define(['foundation']` correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM + Zurb Foundation + WebPack: Cannot resolve module 'foundation'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297788/npm-zurb-foundation-webpack-cannot-resolve-module-foundation)

Comment: I opened a bug report at GitHub, see here https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/7386

Comment: Yep, it's a dup and solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35373347/736518