# NPM + Zurb Foundation + WebPack: Cannot resolve module 'foundation'

Tags: npm, zurb-foundation, webpack

I am working on using Zurb Foundation with WebPack and NPM, *without* Bower.

The problem I am encountering is the same as this below:

https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/7386

Essentially, when installing foundation-sites via NPM, there are references to a module "foundation" that is not found.  The error:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'foundation' in c:\Users\Matt\Documents\Projects\test\node_modules\foundation-sites\dist
 @ ./~/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js
```

Here's the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "foundation-sites": "6.0.5",
    "webpack": "~1.12.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~1.2",
    "jquery": "2.1.1"
  }
}
```

And here is webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
    entry: {
      main: "./app/js/main.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
              },
              { test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue' }
        ],
        resolve: {
            modulesDirectories: ['node_modules']
        }
    },
     sassLoader: {
            includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/")]
          },
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/api/*': {
                target: 'http://localhost:4567',
                secure: false
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I can work around this by including foundation via bower instead, but I want to eliminate bower and use only NPM.

Comment: timaschew's answer was easiest for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/35373347/1783439

Answer (score 16):

I have same problem, but I don't want have two .js files (vendor and app)!

For me, everything need be on a single file, so, I make this:

In **webpack.conf.js**, use externals (maybe have another way without external, but for me, this is sufficient):

```
externals: {
    jQuery: 'jQuery',
    foundation: 'Foundation'
},
```

create a file in your source folder (any name, like **/libs/foundation.js**):

```
// jQuery
var $ = require('jquery');
global.jQuery = $;

// if you want all features of foundation
require('./node_modules_folder/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js');

// if you want only some features
// require('./node_modules/what-input/what-input');
// require('./node_modules/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core');
// require('./node_modules/foundation-sites/js/....');

export default Foundation;
```

now, you can use Foundation in any js using following syntax:

```
import Foundation from './libs/foundation';
```

Comment: Yes it certainly did.  I was trying to integrate it with react-boilerplate, and this seems to have done it.  Now onto the sites :)

Answer (score 7):

I'll post my complete workaround based on Mason Houtz and pharmakon's great answers in case it helps someone, since I struggled with it a bit, learning Webpack in the process.

In my case I had an added complication, because other jQuery plugins were somehow working only inside their own module, while outside their properties were `undefined`. Apparently they were using a local, duplicate jQuery object.

Anyway, here's what you need to do:

1. Install scripts-loader: `npm install --save-dev script-loader`
2. In Webpack's config:

   - Add new entry, let's call it `vendor`. This will compile a new `vendor.js` whenever Webpack runs.

     ```
     entry: {
         ...,
         "vendor": [
             "!!script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
             "!!script!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js"
         ]
     },
     ```
   - Add `jquery` to externals. This makes sure any references to `jquery` inside your main JS will be replaced with a reference to global `jQuery` variable, which is made available by `vendor.js` above.

     ```
     entry : {
         // ...
     },
     externals: {
         jquery: "jQuery"
     }
     ```
3. Make sure every module that uses jQuery imports it:

   ```
   var $ = require('jquery');
   ```

The `externals` config above will replace it with a reference to global `jQuery` variable, instead of re-importing duplicate jQuery "properly".
Optionally you could make use of ProvidePlugin, which will automatically do the above whenever it encounters jQuery in a module, saving you a few keystrokes. If you want that, put the following in Webpack's config:

```
plugins: [
    // ...,
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      '$': 'jquery', 
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
]
```

4. Include the new `vendor.js` to your page, obviously before the main JS.

It's quite possible there's an easier or more elegant way to do this, but I just wanted a quick, working solution, until Foundation hopefully fixes the issue soon.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to do this with webpack by essentially doing an end-run around loading it as a module.

This is basically a hack though, Foundation really needs to update its JS to be loadable as a commonJS module.

The problem stems from Foundation's JS referencing dependencies in erratic ways from within nested IFFEs in the souce code. Sometimes jQuery is the local jQuery parameter, sometimes it's $, sometimes it's window.jQuery. It's really a mixed-bag. The combination of all the different mechanisms means there's no single shimming solution other than to just load the thing non-modularly.

Honestly it's pretty much amateur hour in there, but as of this writing they just released the thing last week, so hopefully it'll be fixed soon.

Anyhoo... to the hack:

I make a separate vendor bundle and load all the amateur-hour 3rd party npm libraries there because I just get tired of fighting with all the various shimming mechanisms necessary to wrap poorly-shipped open-source npm package code.

My vendor bundle is a separate entry point that I register with webpack, and it contains all the libraries that do not play nice as modules.

```
require('!!script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');

require('!!script!uglify!foundation-sites/js/foundation.core.js');
require('!!script!uglify!foundation-sites/js/foundation.accordion.js');
require('!!script!uglify!foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.keyboard.js');
require('!!script!uglify!foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.motion.js');
// etc.
```

Make sure you have script-loader installed

```
npm install script-loader -D
```

The !! means "Ignore all the other rules I already defined in the config". Using the script-loader tells webpack to load and execute the file in the window scope essentially the same as if you had just included a script tag on your page. (But it doesn't, obviously.)

You could get fancier and write your own resolve rules so that it checks just stuff in the foundation-library, but I didn't bother because I hope a library as pervasive as Foundation gets their act together in the near future so I can just delete this hack.

Also... in your main webpack configuration you will want to reference jQuery and any other global window variables loaded in this way as externals.

```
var webpackConfig = {
    entry: { // blah },
    output: { // blah },
    loaders: [ // blah ],
    externals: {
        jquery: "jQuery"
    }
};
```

Comment: How do you provide jQuery to foundation scripts using such require shimming?

Comment: Ahhh, sorry I only posted a fragment of my vendor bundle. Higher up in my vendor bundle I do that, in basically the same way. Will update answer.

Comment: Sadly i'm getting a 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).foundation is not a function'  on the browser :( . Whould be very nice a complete example...

Comment: Where are you putting $(document).foundation(); ? I'm getting the same error as slothy after creating a separate vendor entry.

Comment: @Mihail I think for all approaches, you'll need to do a `import $ as jquery` or `$ = jquery = require('jquery')`

Answer (score 5):

Just use the script-loader (`npm i script-loader`) and prefix your imports with a `script!`.
Then it will be evaluated in the global scope.

To load all js files from foundation use this

```
import 'script!jquery'
import 'script!what-input'
import 'script!foundation-sites'
```

Like I do it in my [entry point](https://github.com/timaschew/r3-foundation-boilerplate/blob/master/src/containers/app.js#L12-L15)

You can check out my boilerplate project to try it out: https://github.com/timaschew/r3-foundation-boilerplate

Comment: thanks, had to look at your template for a while to get styles working

Comment: This worked for sticky nav and vue.js once I added `externals: { foundation: 'Foundation' },` to webpack.conf per Roberto Correia solution

Answer (score 4):

While @roberto's answer looks great, I wanted to provide a simpler solution (in which it does not require any extra vendor/foundation files).

In your webpack config use this:

```js
// this will force the export of the jQuery 'foundation' function, 
// which we'll use later on
loaders: [
  {
    test: /(foundation\.core)/,
    loader: 'exports?foundation=jQuery.fn.foundation'
  }
],

// this makes sure that every module can resolve define(['foundation']) calls
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js'],
  alias: {
    foundation: 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.core'
  }
},

// this makes sure 'jQuery' is available to any jQuery plugin you might want 
// to load (including Foundation files) regardless of how they are written
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
  })
]
```

And in your index.js:

```js
// thanks to the ProvidePlugin we don't need to
// > import $ from 'jquery';

// required core foundation files
import { foundation } from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.core';
import 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.mediaQuery';

/* import here any additional module */

// we need to attach the function we force-exported in the config
// above to the jQuery object in use in this file
$.fn.foundation = foundation;

// ready to go
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).foundation();
  …
});
```

**NOTE #1** (thank you @mtyson)
You need to use the exports loader: `$ npm install --save exports-loader` or `$ npm install --save-dev exports-loader`

**NOTE #2**
Since jQuery is not global inside single modules (or for some other reason that is beyond my understanding), there might be problems relying on `data-` attributes for Foundation JS components. If that is the case, you can always use the pure javascript way as documented in Foundation docs.

Comment: I had to include this in my package.json: "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",

Comment: Also, to make styles work, had to look at foundation-everything include as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35373347/467240

Comment: When I attempt to use this with `foundation.dropdown` I get an error `Cannot read property 'register' of undefined`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I am using the hack. I put foundation and jquery in a separate entry point called vendor and loaded them with the script-loader. The only relevant bits are in the vendor entry point.

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var hotMiddlewareScript = 'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000&reload=true';
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  name: 'main',

  devtool: 'eval',

  entry: {
    client: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'index.js'),
      hotMiddlewareScript
    ],
    vendor: [
      'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
      'foundation-sites/dist/foundation-flex.css',
      '!!script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
      '!!script!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js',
    ]
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },

  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', './client'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.bundle.js'),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({'$': 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery'})
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/, include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client') },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style!css!autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 versions!sass" },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
      // { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.(webm|mp4|mov|m4v|ogg)$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=videos/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)/, loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]' }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for webpack if you can tell it to ignore the `define` test for the troublesome code below:

```
  if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined')
     module.exports = Reveal;
  if (typeof define === 'function')
     define(['foundation'], function() {
     return Reveal;
  });
```

The best way to do that is to use the [imports-loader](https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader) and set `define` to false.

```
require('foundation-sites/js/foundation.core.js');
require('foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.keyboard.js');
require('foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.box.js');
require('foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.triggers.js');
require('foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.mediaQuery.js');
require('foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.motion.js');
require('imports?define=>false!foundation-sites/js/foundation.reveal.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you carefully see the **foundation-sites 6.2.0** modules, you will find the changes in path as following

1. *foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css*
2. *foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js*

So basically you have to changes in webpack confing files entry as following

```
module.exports =  {
         entry: ['script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'script!foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js',
         './app/app.jsx'
       ]
}
```

and the entry for style should be like this

`require('style!css!foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css');`

Answer (score 1):

For myself, I used this solution:

I'm using the Laravel framework, so **first** I added the `.webpackConfig (...)` method to the `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')

// By default, files from the directory "/node_modules" are not processed by the Babel loader,
// so in the Webpack configuration,
// an exception was added for loading from the directory "/node_modules/foundation-sites/js".
.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [{
            // Section "// Babel Compilation." from "/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/webpack-rules.js"
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            // Thanks for the help with "exclude": http://qaru.site/questions/97960/import-a-module-from-nodemodules-with-babel-but-failed/624982#624982
            exclude(file) {
                if (file.startsWith(__dirname + '/node_modules/foundation-sites/js')) {
                    return false;
                }
                return file.startsWith(__dirname + '/node_modules');
            },
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: Config.babel()
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
});
```

**Note:**
To install `Foundation` I used the package https://github.com/laravel-frontend-presets/zurb-foundation. And added the code to load `Foundation` into the `/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` file:

```
/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Foundation jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Foundation features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation'); // 'foundation.min' can also be used if you like

    // The app plugins for the Foundation
    require('./plugins/entries/foundation');

} catch (e) {}
```

**Secondly**, I created the file `/resources/assets/js/plugins/entries/foundation.js` (The file is included in the code above `// The app plugins for the Foundation.`). In which I included my modules (example):

```
import { CropText } from '../cropText';
Foundation.plugin(CropText, 'CropText');
```

**Third**, I created two files for including the `Foundation` plugins:

1) `/resources/assets/js/plugins/foundation.plugin.js`

```
// By default, files from the directory "/node_modules" are not processed by the Babel loader,
// so in the Webpack configuration,
// an exception was added for loading from the directory "/node_modules/foundation-sites/js".
import { Plugin } from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.plugin';

export {Plugin};
```

2) `/resources/assets/js/plugins/foundation.util.mediaQuery.js`

```
// By default, files from the directory "/node_modules" are not processed by the Babel loader,
// so in the Webpack configuration,
// an exception was added for loading from the directory "/node_modules/foundation-sites/js".
import { MediaQuery } from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.mediaQuery';

export {MediaQuery};
```

**In the fourth**, I created a file for my plugin using the `Foundation` plugins template, which include 2 of the above files:

`/resources/assets/js/plugins/cropText.js`

```
'use strict';

import $ from 'jquery';
import { MediaQuery } from './foundation.util.mediaQuery';
import { Plugin } from './foundation.plugin';

/**
 * CropText plugin.
 * @plugin app.cropText
 */
class CropText extends Plugin {
    /**
     * Creates a new instance of CropText.
     * @class
     * @name CropText
     * @fires CropText#init
     * @param {Object} element - jQuery object to add the trigger to.
     * @param {Object} options - Overrides to the default plugin settings.
     */
    _setup(element, options = {}) {
        this.$element = element;
        this.options  = $.extend(true, {}, CropText.defaults, this.$element.data(), options);

        this.className = 'CropText'; // ie9 back compat
        this._init();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the CropText plugin.
     * @private
     */
    _init() {
        MediaQuery._init();

        this.cropText();
    }

    /**
     * Crops the text.
     */
    cropText() {
        var size = +this.options.cropSize;

        $(this.$element).each(function(i, value) {
            var $valueText = $(value).text(),
                $valueHtml = $(value).html();

            if($valueText.length > size){
                $(value).html('<span>' + $valueText.slice(0, size).trim() + '</span>' + '...').wrapInner('<a></a>');

                var revealId = '#' + $(value).attr('data-open');

                if ($(revealId + ' .close-button').attr('data-close') != undefined) {
                    $(revealId + ' .close-button').before($valueHtml);
                } else {
                    $(revealId).append($valueHtml);
                }

                new Foundation.Reveal($(revealId), {
                    'data-overlay' : false
                });
            } else {
                $(value).removeAttr('data-open').removeAttr('tabindex');
            }
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Default settings for plugin
 */
CropText.defaults = {
    /**
     * The size of the cropped text.
     * @option
     * @type {number}
     * @default 255
     */
    cropSize: 255
};

export {CropText};
```

**It's all.** Next, I just need to include a standard JavaScript file in the HTML code of the page and initialize the Foundation (example):

`/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`

```
<script src=" {{ mix('/js/app.js') }} "></script>

<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

P.S. Sorry for my English ;-), I used Google Translate.

Answer (score 1):

This is the common place to land from web search with beginner questions related to the technologies mentioned in the question.

Here is my  [Zurb Foundation with SCSS and Webpack Example Project](https://github.com/pelamfi/zurb-foundation-scss-webpack-example).

Feel free to clone it. It is licensed with the Unlicense.

### Background

Although, the module compatibility issues are resolved with recent (> 6.4) versions of the Zurb Foundation, a basic setup may still seem like black magic for a beginner. I think there must be other and probably better examples like mine somewhere, but I just couldn't find them. I'm adding the fruits of my learning journey here in the hopes that it will make somebody's ride a bit less bumpy.